# can't insert unix timestamp into table's timestamp field

Tags: mysql

I have the table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tt (
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  date timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Now I'm trying to insert a record:

```
INSERT INTO tt (name, date) VALUES('some', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()));
```

And get the following error:

```
Incorrect datetime value: '1428306271' for column 'date' at row 1
```

How can that be?

**EDIT**:
This option also produces an error:

```
INSERT INTO tt (name, date) VALUES('some', UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

Comment: in which format youwant to insert data in your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
INSERT INTO tt (name, date) VALUES('some', now());
```

`date timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL` will accept the values as 
`yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s`

Comment: thanks, it works with `now()`, but it inserts the value as `4/6/2015 10:59:33 AM`. Can I insert the value as unix timestamp, e.g. `1428306271`?

Comment: In that case the data type should be `int` or `varchar`. But I would suggest to use `Y-m-d H:i:s` since later doing the query with range, finding data for a specific year etc will be such simpler than storing the integer values.

Comment: right, thanks, and if I get the value from client side as `1428306271`, I'll be able to use `FROM_UNIXTIME1428306271)` on insert, and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` on query, correct? Would you also advice to use `datetime` field type or `timestamp`?

Comment: If you receive data from client side as `1428306271` then yes you can use `from_unixtime()` and while returning data to client can use `unix_timestamp()` but good practice would be store as I said earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have current date time in field in format 2015-04-06 13:24:42,you should not require to add this field to query as it will automatically update current date time value in this format to database.

So your query will be : INSERT INTO tt (name) VALUES('some');

suppose current date time is 2015-04-06 13:24:42 so this will automatically updated to you date field ind database.

It will be as per UTC time.

Answer (score -1):

`TO_TIMESTAMP` is the function to convert `epoch` to `timestamp`

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name, time) VALUES ('Hello', TO_TIMESTAMP(123))
```